# Groovy Error unexpected token: @ line

Tags: groovy

I'm getting the following error in Groovy 2.1

```
 script1409163855794789083714.groovy: 53: unexpected token:  @ line
```

Two questions here
1 - Doesn't it normally say what the token is that's causing the issue? What's it mean when it's blank?
2 - Since it isn't saying the script name, it's giving me script, does that mean this issue is in a class that my script is calling, and not the primary one?

What's odd is, I don't get an error when I run it with Groovy 2.0*. So this might be difficult for anyone else to replicate. I'm jsut asking what the error message means in general, not trying to get someone to solve my problem for me :)

EDIT - The error isn't on line 53 at all, I've narrowed it down to this line. Tim Yates might be onto something in his comment below, but retyping it didn't help.

config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("D:/schedule/cm/dev/riv11a/ssi/RIV-ssi.groovy").text)

EDIT - This line parses a configSlurper file that has a line that looks like var=

So that's the error. Thank you!! I really wish groovy would tell you which file your error is in.

Comment: Add the script and the class that is being used by the script.

Comment: You might have got a weird unprintable char in your script... If you delete that block and type (don't paste) it back in, does it help?

Comment: What is the actual value of `sqlResults.path`? If is just a path then you have to add a closure to include the desired file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of code that worked for me:

```
def flags = releaseConf.releaseMailFlags.value
def attachments = [
   (flags.contains('qrCode') && releaseConf.QRCodeFile?.location?.exists() ? releaseConf.QRCodeFile.location : null),
   (flags.contains('imageMontage') && releaseConf. `?.location?.exists() ? releaseConf.imageMontageFile.location : null)
]
attachments.removeAll([null])

ant.mail(
    mailhost: releaseConf.mailServer,
    mailport: releaseConf.mailPort,
    subject: releaseConf.releaseMailSubject,
    charset: 'UTF-8',
    tolist: releaseConf.releaseMailTo.value.join(','),
    from: releaseConf.releaseMailFrom.value,
    message: releaseConf.mailMessageFile?.location?.text,
    messageMimeType: 'text/html',
    files: attachments.join(',')
)
```

`QRCodeFile` and `imageMontageFile` *location* fields are instances of a `java.io.File` class. So a collection of absolute paths is passed separated with `,` is set under `files` key.